# Select what I want with an argument in python

Tags: python

I have a function (that is huge and you don't need to read it, especially cause it's not in english and it is dependent of other functions) that I have as an argument "strat". This function is basically artificial intelligence (it's the robot of the game in question, tic tac toe) and with the argument "strat" I want to filter the parameters that the function has. What I mean by this is that this function has 6 "possibilities" of action and by selecting a different strat I want to narrow those. If strat = 'basic' then it will only read the parameter 3, 5 and 6 but if I write 'normal' it will read everything. This means that the function receives the arguments and goes by order and it checks the first that fulfills the requirements, if not it jumps to the next. This might be confusing but I'll give an example, don't worry with the function, just with what has **#number**

```
def chose(tab,n,strat):
                                    #1 Victory

    if strat != 'basic':
        if identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_coluna(tab, 1), n) is True:
            if obter_coluna(tab, 1)[0] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[1] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 1)[0] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,4)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[1] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_coluna(tab, 2), n) is True:
            if obter_coluna(tab, 2)[0] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[1] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,8)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 2)[0] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[1] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,2)        
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_coluna(tab, 3), n) is True:
            if obter_coluna(tab, 3)[0] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[1] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 3)[0] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[1] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,6)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 3)[0] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[1] == n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
            
            #Determinar Linhas
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_linha(tab, 1), n) is True:
            if obter_linha(tab, 1)[0] == n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[1] == n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 1)[0] == n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 1)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,2)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 1)[1] == n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_linha(tab, 2), n) is True:
            if obter_linha(tab, 2)[0] == n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[1] == n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,6)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 2)[0] == n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 2)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 2)[1] == n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,4)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_linha(tab, 3), n) is True:
            if obter_linha(tab, 3)[0] == n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[1] == n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 3)[0] == n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[1] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 3)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,8)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 3)[0] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 3)[1] == n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
            
            #Determinar nas diagonais
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_diagonal(tab, 1), n) is True:
            if obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[0] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[1] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[0] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[1] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_pertencentes(obter_diagonal(tab, 2), n) is True:
            if obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[0] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[1] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[0] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[1] == n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[2] == n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)

    
    
                                            #2 Block


    elif strat != 'basic':   
        if identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_coluna(tab, 1), n) is True:
            if obter_coluna(tab, 1)[0] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[1] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 1)[0] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,4)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[1] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 1)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_coluna(tab, 2), n) is True:
            if obter_coluna(tab, 2)[0] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[1] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,8)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 2)[0] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[1] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 2)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,2)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_coluna(tab, 3), n) is True:
            if obter_coluna(tab, 3)[0] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[1] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 3)[0] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[1] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,6)
            elif obter_coluna(tab, 3)[0] == 0 and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[1] == -n and obter_coluna(tab, 3)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_linha(tab, 1), n) is True:
            if obter_linha(tab, 1)[0] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[1] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 1)[0] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 1)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,2)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 1)[1] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 1)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_linha(tab, 2), n) is True:
            if obter_linha(tab, 2)[0] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[1] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,6)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 2)[0] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 2)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 2)[1] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 2)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,4)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_linha(tab, 3), n) is True:
            if obter_linha(tab, 3)[0] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[1] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 3)[0] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[1] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 3)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,8)
            elif obter_linha(tab, 3)[0] == 0 and obter_linha(tab, 3)[1] == -n and obter_linha(tab, 3)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_diagonal(tab, 1), n) is True:
            if obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[0] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[1] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[0] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[1] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[0] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[1] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 1)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
            
        elif identificar_tuplos_nao_pertencentes(obter_diagonal(tab, 2), n) is True:
            if obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[0] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[1] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[2] == 0:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[0] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[1] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)
            elif obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[0] == 0 and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[1] == -n and obter_diagonal(tab, 2)[2] == -n:
                return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
    
    
                            #3 Center

    elif tab[1][1] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,5)

    
                       #4 Opposite Corner

    elif strat != 'basic':
        if tab[0][0] != -n and tab[2][2] == 0:
            return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)
        elif tab[0][2] != -n and tab[2][0] == 0:
            return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
        elif tab[2][0] != -n and tab[0][2] == 0:
            return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
        elif tab[2][2] != -n and tab[0][0] == 0:
            return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)

    
                             #5 Empty Corner

    elif tab[0][0] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,1)
    elif tab[0][2] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,3)
    elif tab[2][0] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,7)
    elif tab[2][2] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,9)

    
                           #6 What's left
    elif tab [0][1] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,2)
    elif tab [1][0] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,4)
    elif tab [1][2] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,6)
    elif tab [2][1] == 0:
        return marcar_posicao(tab,n,8)
```

Looking at this, if I wrote "chose(tab,n,'basic') ,and tab and n are irrelevant for this in this example, the function would jump number 1 and 2 and go to 3 and if 3 doesn't work then it would jump number 4 and it would go to 5 and then if necessary 6.What I did was to put those lines "elif strat != 'basic':" before the number but it doesn't work and I don't know why. This works if I strat == 'basic' but if strat == 'normal' then it won't work. This is specially annoying because in my actual code, strat can be 3 different things.
I hope you can understand my question. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You can pass functions as parameters, and store functions in lists, that would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach might be something like defining your actions as functions, then storing those actions in lists e.g.

```
def action_any_empty(board):
...

def action_empty_corner(board):
...

def action_opposite_corner(board):
...

easy =   [action_any_empty]
medium = [action_empty_corner] + easy
hard =   [action_opposite_corner] + medium

strats={"easy":easy,"medium":medium,"hard":hard}

for action in strats[difficulty]:
    move = action(board)
    if move:
        return move
```

It might be better to have them as classes rather than just functions, they can then all inherit form some parent 'action' class and it's safer to iterate over them.

Comment: it says that I can't do it with two functions

Comment: What says you can't do what with two functions? you could still have a single 'chose' function but use this logic to manage the actions and eventual output of that function